# Relative angular velocity of point with respect to another point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

What is relative angular velocity of one point, say A, with respect to another point, say B? Both the points lie on the same rigid body which is rotating with constant angular velocity ω about a fixed axis.

Edit:

Here is the figure
[image]

The above body is rigid. For simplicity consider the rod joining A and B to be massless. So is the relative angular velocity of A with respect to B be zero? And if this is the case then how my question is different from [Relative angular velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485970/relative-angular-velocity)

I think i'm missing something.

Comment: I will return with a proper answer.

Comment: They are at rest wrt each other thus answer is $0$

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573208/260770) should be helpful.

Comment: @Eli's answer below gives a mathematical proof that the relative angular velocity is zero. From an intuitive point of view, imagine sitting at point B and looking at point A. As the rigid body rotates, A remains fixed your field of view, so no angular velocity with respect to you.

Comment: @dark_prince Even I feel the same as others and the answer should be zero.

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: Answer will be omega. @Eli solved it. He just miscalculated the last step considering it to be scalar triple product. It's a vector triple product if you expand it you will get omega only.

Comment: @dark_prince You are right. The answer is omega. I think most people including myself answered zero because they underestimated the question to be a very simple one. Anyways I am removing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The relative angular velocity$~\vec{\omega}_{r}~$ can obtain from this  equation:

$$\vec{\omega}_{r}=\frac{\vec{R}_{AB}\times \vec{V}_{AB} }{\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB}}\tag 1$$

with :

$$\vec{R}_{AB}=\vec{R}_{B}-\vec{R}_{A}$$
$$\vec{V}_{AB}=\vec{V}_{B}-\vec{V}_{A}$$

equation (1)

$$\vec{\omega}_{r}=\frac{\left(\vec{R}_{B}-\vec{R}_{A}\right)\times \left(\vec{V}_{B}-\vec{V}_{A}\right) }{\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB}}\tag 2$$

with $~\vec{V}_A=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{R}_A~$ and
$~\vec{V}_B=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{R}_B~$

equation (2)

$$\vec{\omega}_{r}=\frac{\vec{R}_{AB}\times (\vec{\omega}\times \vec{R}_{AB})}{\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB}}=\frac{(\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB})\vec{\omega} -  ( \vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{\omega})\vec{R}_{AB}}{\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB}}\tag 3$$

Now if A and B lie in the plane perpendicular to ω then $$\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{\omega} = \vec{0}$$

equation (3) becomes:

$$\vec{\omega}_{r} = \frac{(\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB})\vec{\omega}}{\vec{R}_{AB}\cdot \vec{R}_{AB}} = \vec{\omega}$$

thus the relative angular velocity is ω.

Comment: Please see edited question.

Comment: @dark_prince $\overrightarrow{a}\times \overrightarrow{b}\times \overrightarrow{a}=-\overrightarrow{b}\times \overrightarrow{a}\times \overrightarrow{a}=\overrightarrow{0}$

Comment: NO!! https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9d5ccb6c880c36b1c1e53b76d8d236f2bfeb3ad8

Comment: You can't do that. Search vector triple product

Comment: O.k I agree with you . I will correct my results

Comment: @dark_prince thanks for your revision

Answer (score 3):

I tried above to give an intuitive explanation of why the answer was zero. I will try to do the same for the new answer, ω (I'm flexible !). So again, imagine you are sitting at point B and looking at point A. As the rigid body rotates, A remains fixed your field of view, which led me before to say the relative angular velocity was zero. But as the object rotates, A faces different directions in the environment of the object so it appears to rotate once for each rotation of the object (as our moon rotates once a month despite always showing the same face to us). Make sense?

Comment: Yes, perfectly! So that's what happening even if B's head remain fixed A will appear to move.

Comment: Another thing to note: relative velocity should not be zero to have a non zero relative angular velocity. Imagine B to be situated below A at the same distance from axis; here relative angular velocity will be zero because relative velocity is zero. Your analogy fits here if we look from B, A will face the same direction i.e. upwards. B will always look upwards wrt to the environment

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by below A, but it would seem no matter where B is an observer on B would notice that a spot on A faced in succession 360 degrees around the environment of the object thus again appearing to rotate once for each rotation of the object.

Comment: Assume a cylinder, A is on top face and B is on bottom face, both at the boundary(distance from the axis is same). Now B will look at A in upward direction and wrt to the environment B's view will not change. So B will notice the angular velocity of A is zero. (here relative velocity of A wrt B is zero and so is relative angular velocity)

Comment: The axis of rotation of the cylinder is through the center of the faces? If A had a mark on it, it seems to me that B would still see that mark in turn face 360 degrees around the environment of the object for each rotation of the object. So A would still have a relative angular velocity of ω. But @Eli's proof assumes they lie in a plane perpendicular to the axis of rotation ??

Comment: I've posted a new question. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576855/relative-angular-velocity-of-one-point-with-respect-to-another-on-a-solid-rigid